# When i Execute Python dot py file Its shows nothing

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

when i am executing the below code it shows nothing.. 
OS:Window 8.1
Python Version:3.7.4

```
    import os
    from sqlalchemy import create_engine
    from sqlalchemy.orm import scoped_session, sessionmaker

    engine = create_engine("postgresql://postgres:123@127.0.0.1:62621/postgres")
    db = scoped_session(sessionmaker(bind=engine))

def main():
    flights = db.execute("SELECT origin, destination, duration FROM flights").fetchall() 
for flight in flights:
    print(f"{flight.origin} to {flight.destination}, {flight.duration} minutes.")
    if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G2kz9.png)

Comment: The `if` statement should not be indented.

Comment: Because of that, you're never calling `main()`.

Answer (score 1):

You are not executing main. This block

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
        main()
```

should be out of the main function

Answer (score 0):

Your indent is wrong through all your code. Try something like this:

```
import os
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import scoped_session, sessionmaker

engine = create_engine("postgresql://postgres:123@127.0.0.1:62621/postgres")
db = scoped_session(sessionmaker(bind=engine))

def main():
    flights = db.execute("SELECT origin, destination, duration FROM flights").fetchall() 
    for flight in flights:
        print(f"{flight.origin} to {flight.destination}, {flight.duration} minutes.")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Also, I encourage you to read a little on Python's indentation documentation: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#indentation